# How to get data from joined tables when performing a merge?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to use a merge to a table.
What I am having trouble with is getting the matching name from the code that exists in the original table. I will put my code and explain further:

```
MERGE INTO ResultTable R
USING InitialTable IT
ON (false)
WHEN MATCHED THEN -- do some stuff
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (PrimaryKey,..., ThingFromJoinedTable)
VALUES (Seq.NEXTVAL, ..., ??? );
```

So the Initial table has a foreign key and I want to get the matching value in the Joined table.

Anyone have any idea on how to do so, I have tried having a nested select with a join, but it gives me a `single-row subquery returns more than one row` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
MERGE INTO ResultTable R
USING ( SELECT it.this, it.that, third.this, third.that
        FROM   InitialTable it
        JOIN   ThirdTable third ON <your join criteria> ) SRC
/* depending on which columns you want for the join */
ON (r.col1 = src.col1 and r.col2 = src.col2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN -- do some stuff
/* depending on which columns you need to merge */
UPDATE SET
    r.col4 = src.col4,
    r.col5 = src.col5,
    etc.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (PrimaryKey,..., colThis, colThat, ....)
VALUES (Seq.NEXTVAL, ..., src.colThis, src.colThat );
```

Comment: I have the top part working (When it is merged), however what I cannot figure out is the last part of the insert where I would like to insert data from a third table that is related to the InitialTable

Comment: You will have to join in the third table in the USING clause. I will modify my answer to show how.

Comment: Thank you, just a small question. What does the SRC denote here?

Comment: SRC is just an alias I chose for the sub-query joining the third table. You can call it whatever you like. Such a sub-query can be used in place of a regular table e.g. in  a where-clause - or as here in the using-clause.